# How to fix this texture streching?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eYFU.png)

I want to put a texture on only one side of the object or fix the streching in any way.
Is there any way to do this in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

This an expected bahavior for default UV mapping. You can try to use tool like ProBuilder to redo the UV Mapping within the engine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).